# What probability distribution is to the discrete uniform distribution as the beta distribution is to uniform distribution over $[0,1]$?

Tags: probability, distributions, uniform-distribution, beta-distribution

A beta distribution with its parameters $\alpha = \beta = 1$ is the uniform $[0, 1]$ distribution.

What distribution is to the discrete uniform distribution (the sample space is left undecided), as the beta distribution is to the uniform distribution over $[0,1]$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution with equal $p$? Or I'm not understanding you

Comment: Thanks! Do multinomial distribution and beta distribution bear some resemblance?

Comment: And the dirichlet with the multinomial

Comment: Migrating by OP request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the [beta-binomial distribution. From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_model):

> For *α* = *β* = 1, it is the [discrete uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution) from 0 to *n*. It also approximates the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) arbitrarily well for large *α* and *β*. The beta-binomial is a one-dimensional version of the [Dirichlet-multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet-multinomial_distribution), as the binomial and beta distributions are special cases of the [multinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) and [Dirichlet distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution), respectively.

This answer might be compatible with @user777's, but I'm uncertain of this.

Comment: (+1) I suppose the answer depends on what, precisely, Tim means. If he means that the outcome of the process is allocated randomly to, e.g., categories, A, B, and C, then my answer is correct. If he means that the outcome is chosen uniformly from integer values between $0$ and $n$, then your answer is correct. (FWIW, I think he means the latter.)

Answer (score 3):

Dirichlet such that all probabilities are equal. The Dirichlet is the beta distribution extended to two or more outcomes. In fact, a Dirichlet for two outcome categories **is** beta.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the other answers, I suppose you could say that the discrete uniform can be seen as a special case of a number of distributions.  However, the simplest would be the [categorical distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution) with all category probabilities equal ($\forall i,j\ \ p_i=p_j$).